# core data with tableview

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5, tableview, storyboard

im using storyboard and core data my entires are being updated in the database but not being reflected in my tableview when it comes to my fetchedrequestcontroller n ans sets the entity it crashes any clue as to why im posting the code below thanks for any help.

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchResultsController
{
    if(fetchResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Persons" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSFetchedResultsController *afetchresultscontroller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    afetchresultscontroller.delegate = self;
    self.fetchResultsController = afetchresultscontroller;

    return fetchResultsController;
}
```

Comment: it crashes right after  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

Comment: Please include the details of the crash

Comment: can no one answer this question???????

Comment: You aren't giving enough information. What is the stack trace from the crash?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine.

Post the stack trace of the crash for someone to assist you further.